# Is this file qualified for Sphinx training

Tags: voice-recognition, voice-recording, sphinx4

[My WAV](https://www.mediafire.com/?z41zvvorkg5qfcv) has some small buzzing sound at its beginning and end. Is this file qualified for Sphinx training? If yes, do I have to include some special character in the transcription file?

Thank you and best regards.

Comment: How this question is related to SO?

Comment: I admit that it seems trivial, but IMHO, I guess the answer could save the effort to train incorrect sound when it comes to Sphinx

Comment: It's not about question being trivial. Stack Overflow is for questions about programming, your question is not related to programing at all.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can simply cut your wav and remove the sound.

Secondly, if you have one wav, there is no point training anything, you need lots of data.

You can add a special sound "buzz" in your transcription, model, vocabulary, etc. and account for it. I would rather get rid of it if possible. Though, if your mic buzzes all the time, you may choose to leave it.

In general your training data should be recorded under the same conditions the system will be used.